# QGIS Plugin with save settings dialog

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, pyqt

I am writing on an update of the qgis2leaf plugin. 
It would be great to store the settings of the plugin UI (like which checkboxes are checked, which strings are used) in a separate file (like xml or sth. else). secondly it would be great to load such a file and set the UI with the parameters in this file.

Does anyone know a plugin for qgis that might already have such a functionality so I can use it as a template?

Comment: Try looking at the constraints checker  http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ConstraintChecker/

Comment: You could always use Python's ConfigParser: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html to store setting in "ini" files.

Answer (score 5):

You can use QSettings to read and write settings. It takes care of storing the settings on all platforms without you having to find a place to write a file.

I used this functionality in the Google Maps Engine Connector plugin to store UI settings
https://github.com/NathanW2/mapsengine-qgis-connector/blob/master/plugin/settings.py

Comment: Hi Ujaval. Thanks for the hint. I thought about this as well but sometimes you need different settinmgs for different projects. So having different "settings files" can be an advantage.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can store settings in separate files/ways with `QSettings`, and within the same `Q(Core)Application`. This makes it ideal for what you are looking to do.

When initializing your PyQGIS plugin's `QSettings`, you will want to do something like this for a [standard settings setup](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#QSettings-3):

```
my_settings = QtCore.QSettings(QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat,
                               QtCore.QSettings.UserScope,
                               'MyOrganization', 'MyApp')
```

Or for a [standalone file](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#QSettings-4) setup:

```
my_settings = QtCore.QSettings("/path/to/mysettings.ini",
                               QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
```

***Edit:*** if you are going to use a standalone file, consider storing it in the `QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()` directory, e.g. usually resolves to `~/.qgis2/`.

What you DO NOT want to do, like many PyQGIS plugin developers have often done, is the following:

```
my_settings = QtCore.QSettings()
```

Since your plugin is running inside of an existing `QApplication`, this will (probably) return a reference to **QGIS's** `QSettings` object, which is not necessarily a good place to store plugin settings. Users are often apt to remove those settings in an attempt to fix an issue with the application.

Comment: sounds good, I'll give it a try as it is prob. better than parsing the whole UI in a csv file like described below.

Answer (score 1):

My plugin uses this also:
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geopunt4Qgis/

The dialog that saves the settings:
https://github.com/warrieka/geopunt4Qgis/blob/master/geopunt4QgisSettingsdialog.py

Comment: there is no possibility to store different settings in different files, is there?!

Comment: Not with QSettings

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a plugin that store it's settings in a customizable way. 
ATM I am extracting all the current values and store them in a csv file:

```
my_settings = {"Foldername": self.outFolderName, "Basemap": self.basemapname}
with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_settings.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_settings)
```

The file can be loaded as well:

```
with open('filename.csv'), mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for rows in reader:
        #now restore the settings by mapping the file:
        self.ui.foldername.setText(rows['Foldername'])
        index_basemap = self.ui.basemapbox.findText(rows['Basemap'])
        self.ui.basemapbox.setCurrentIndex(index_basemap)
```