# Keep UI Settings for a QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I'm writing a plugin that interacts with external software (hydrological models).

One of the dialogs has a lot of entries (parameters to pass to the hydrological software).

Once the user has set up all the parameters and the dialog is closed, when the same dialog is re-opened all the previous parameters are gone and the user has to type them again.

What I'd like to achieve is to *save* all the entries in the dialog so the user knows the old parameters added.

Plugin *QGIS2threejs* has this functionality but I'm not able to add the code.

And, is it also possible to store the UI parameters (a kind of *screenshot*) in an external file to that another user can load it and automatically all the fields will be filled?

I saw [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114527/qgis-plugin-with-save-settings-dialog) answer but I'm not sure I can solve my problem in the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, you need to use `QSettings` to store values across QGIS sessions. `QSettings` is multi-platform, so you don't need to worry about where it stores the data on Linux, on Windows, or on Mac, it handles it for you.

You need to call `QSettings` in this way:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings 
settings = QSettings()
```

You can use `QSettings()` every time you need it, from any Python (file) module of your plugin.

To store values:

```
settings.setValue( "/myPlugin/currentTab", self.tabWidget.currentIndex() )
```

To retrieve values:

```
settings.value( "/myPlugin/raster/path", "", type=str )
settings.value( "/myPlugin/config/layersOff", type=bool )
settings.value( "/myPlugin/currentTab", type=int )
```

---

**TIP**: If the path you are using is too long, you can open a block like this:

```
settings.beginGroup( "/myPlugin/config" )
```

Then assign/read several values in this way:

```
settings.setValue( "numLayers", n ) # Saved in /myPlugin/config/numLayers
settings.setValue(...)
settings.setValue(...)
```

And finally, close the block:

```
settings.endGroup()
```

As always, the best way to get to know how to best use QSettings in a plugin is to read other people's plugins.

Additionally, you can have a look at the API docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html

Comment: Hi @Germàn.. Thanks for the super quick answer.. Maybe I did not understand.. I can make an instance of ``QSettings()`` and pass it as parameters also the ``ui`` file **or** should I call the instance each time in the UI python related file for the values I want to store? Because I have a lots of different objects (Lines, ComboBox, etc..).. Anyway, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Have a look at how I store and retrieve QSettings in my LoadThemAll plugin: https://github.com/gacarrillor/loadthemall/blob/b93a4aafc848b7ee4a93235879a2b325e687c990/LoadThemAllDialog.py#L307 It might give you and idea. In each file you need to store/read settings, you can call QSettings(), which will give you access to the settings store. However, nothing prevents you from calling QSettings() from each function you need, as it will give you the same object always.

Comment: You don't have to call the `QSettings()` constructor with a parameter, because the application and organisation parameters mentioned in the API documentation linked to by Germán are provided by QGIS (at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/81c5f25a7f627eb818de1c3d9e4b9e4227b695f1/src/browser/main.cpp#L51, for example)

Comment: Thanks @til_b, that's right. If, on the contrary, you were working on a Python Standalone Application, you would need to assign such values by yourself.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo .. I'm looking at the code of your plugin.. If I get it you have created the functions ``saveConfigTabSettings`` and ``saveBaseSettings`` with all the *objects* of the UI and passing all of them (the ones you want to be saved) in the ``setValue`` parameter. Then in the function ``restoreBaseSettings`` you check all the parameters you want and you pass the settings saved in the other functions.. is this the workflow?

Comment: Right, functions are optional, of course, you could save everything in one function and read it in another function. I use restoreControls and restoreBaseSettings to read stored settings and update my plugin UIs according to what was saved. If there is nothing saved (i.e., first time the user runs my plugin) I set some default values. In summary, when your plugin opens, you check for stored values, if they exist you apply those values in your UI, but if they don't you apply some default values. When the user makes changes, you store those values and the process starts again.

Comment: Ok I think it is pretty clear. The hard work is I have really a lot of objects to save.. :)

Comment: Yeap, but keep in mind that you'll do this once and all users will acknowledge it forever.